# Bullets and numbering within reports

Tags: jasper-reports

How do you add a bullet list and stylized numbered list using JasperReports?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

1. Add static text (or a text field).
2. Set **Markup** in the **Properties** panel to: `html`
3. Use the following HTML markup in the text:

```
<ul>
  <li>bulleted item 1</li>
  <li>bulleted item 2</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>ordered item 1</li>
  <li>ordered item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: To my pleasant surprise, this yields bulleted text regardless of which exporter is being used, HTML, PDF, RTF, etc.

Comment: Hi, this work only if dont has a break line bacause it loss the indent...

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts, where we want to do automatic numbering without CSS styles. I solved this by implementing own JRDataSource.

Comment: you should provide your implementation or some other form of help, this is only a partial answer.

Comment: We achieved this by generating that in the database. It's not ideal but definitely the simplest solution.