# How to add bullet point in TextField

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

I want to add bullet point to my static text and to a text field, i added style tag to the jrxml but it didn't work for me :

Here's the example :

*TextField :*

```xml
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement uuid="cfd514bc-d1c5-4369-b10d-71042b046e37" x="11" y="0" width="400" height="12"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[<style size="40">.</style>$F{LMSG}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

*StaticText:*

```xml
<staticText>
    <reportElement uuid="c1485aba-09a4-4c7b-9106-0893341f1368" x="44" y="107" width="309" height="15"/>
    <textElement>
        <font size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[<style size="40">.</style>Je déduis cet avoir de ma commande]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports - Bullets and Numbering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643256/jasper-reports-bullets-and-numbering)

Answer (score 13):

You can use *styled markup*.

Try to use `<li>` tag.

#### The sample

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="bullet_sample" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="aa7ced41-689a-4b8d-94aa-ee79c243a7a8">
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="bf39def6-a3a7-4fa1-9e99-e488b3567974" x="159" y="31" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<li>Text with bullet</li>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

---

In case using field, the right expression will be:

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="171" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement markup="styled"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<li>" + $F{fieldName} + "</li>"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

---

*Note*:

- You can find more info about *styled text*  in [Style a text field in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8135215/876298) post and in [Styled Text](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/styledtext/index.html#styledtext) sample

Comment: hi thank u , but for the text field it gives an error i use it like this :                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[<li>$F{LMSG}</li>]]></textFieldExpression>

Comment: @AmiraGL Your expression is wrong. I've just add sample to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I used the `<li>` tag, but it introduced padding which did not look good. So, I used "\u2022" which gives a round symbol like

```
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["\u2022 Line1\n\u2022 Line2"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

So, this looks much cleaner